# Error Schedule Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, java-ee, schedule

Estoy realizando una aplicación empresarial con primefaces y necesito añadir un calendario con lo que me he ido al showcase de primefaces y he encontrado el componente que necesito (Se llama Schedule). Para no cargarme el proyecto que tengo, lo que he hecho ha sido crearme uno nuevo y crearme un index.xhtml y un .java en el que he introducido el código que me da Primefaces para así ir probando y viendo como funciona pero no me muestra nada.

He añadido en el proyecto tanto el Framework de JSF como la dependencia de Primefaces (6.2) y no me muestra nada. Os dejo por aquí el código de mi programa que está copiado tal cuál lo tiene la web de Primefaces (https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml).

**Index.xhtml:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            PrimeFaces.locales['tr'] = {
                closeText: 'kapat',
                prevText: 'geri',
                nextText: 'ileri',
                currentText: 'bugün',
                monthNames: ['Ocak', 'Şubat', 'Mart', 'Nisan', 'Mayıs', 'Haziran',
                    'Temmuz', 'Ağustos', 'Eylül', 'Ekim', 'Kasım', 'Aralık'],
                monthNamesShort: ['Oca', 'Şub', 'Mar', 'Nis', 'May', 'Haz',
                    'Tem', 'Ağu', 'Eyl', 'Eki', 'Kas', 'Ara'],
                dayNames: ['Pazar', 'Pazartesi', 'Salı', 'Çarşamba', 'Perşembe', 'Cuma', 'Cumartesi'],
                dayNamesShort: ['Pz', 'Pt', 'Sa', 'Ça', 'Pe', 'Cu', 'Ct'],
                dayNamesMin: ['Pz', 'Pt', 'Sa', 'Ça', 'Pe', 'Cu', 'Ct'],
                weekHeader: 'Hf',
                firstDay: 1,
                isRTL: false,
                showMonthAfterYear: false,
                yearSuffix: '',
                month: 'Ay',
                week: 'Hafta',
                day: 'Gün',
                allDayText: 'Tüm Gün'
            };
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .value {
                width: 1000px;
            }
        </style>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>


        <h:form>
            <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />

            <h:panelGrid columnClasses="value">
                <h3 style="margin-top: 0">Editable Schedule</h3>
                <p:schedule id="schedule" value="#{scheduleView.eventModel}" widgetVar="myschedule" timeZone="GMT+2">

                    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{scheduleView.onDateSelect}" update="eventDetails" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show();" />
                    <p:ajax event="eventSelect" listener="#{scheduleView.onEventSelect}" update="eventDetails" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show();" />
                    <p:ajax event="eventMove" listener="#{scheduleView.onEventMove}" update="messages" />
                    <p:ajax event="eventResize" listener="#{scheduleView.onEventResize}" update="messages" />

                </p:schedule>

                <h3>Locale Support ( Example: Turkish )</h3>
                <p:schedule id="scheduleLocale" value="#{scheduleView.eventModel}" locale="tr" />

                <h3>Lazy Schedule</h3>
                <p:schedule value="#{scheduleView.lazyEventModel}" />
            </h:panelGrid>

            <p:dialog widgetVar="eventDialog" header="Event Details" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip">
                <h:panelGrid id="eventDetails" columns="2">
                    <p:outputLabel for="title" value="Titles:" />
                    <p:inputText id="title" value="#{scheduleView.event.title}" required="true" />

                    <p:outputLabel for="from" value="From:" />
                    <p:calendar id="from" value="#{scheduleView.event.startDate}" timeZone="GMT+2" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"/>

                    <p:outputLabel for="to" value="To:" />
                    <p:calendar id="to" value="#{scheduleView.event.endDate}" timeZone="GMT+2" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"/>

                    <p:outputLabel for="allDay" value="All Day:" />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="allDay" value="#{scheduleView.event.allDay}" />

                    <p:commandButton type="reset" value="Reset" />
                    <p:commandButton id="addButton" value="Save" action="#{scheduleView.addEvent}" oncomplete="PF('myschedule').update();PF('eventDialog').hide();" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:dialog>    
        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

**ScheduleView.java:**

```
package com.g1.calendario;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.primefaces.event.ScheduleEntryMoveEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.ScheduleEntryResizeEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultScheduleEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultScheduleModel;
import org.primefaces.model.LazyScheduleModel;
import org.primefaces.model.ScheduleEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.ScheduleModel;

/**
 *
 * @author Josemanuu
 */
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
@Named
public class ScheduleView implements Serializable {

    private ScheduleModel eventModel;

    private ScheduleModel lazyEventModel;

    private ScheduleEvent event = new DefaultScheduleEvent();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();
        eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Champions League Match", previousDay8Pm(), previousDay11Pm()));
        eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Birthday Party", today1Pm(), today6Pm()));
        eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Breakfast at Tiffanys", nextDay9Am(), nextDay11Am()));
        eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Plant the new garden stuff", theDayAfter3Pm(), fourDaysLater3pm()));

        lazyEventModel = new LazyScheduleModel() {

            @Override
            public void loadEvents(Date start, Date end) {
                Date random = getRandomDate(start);
                addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Lazy Event 1", random, random));

                random = getRandomDate(start);
                addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Lazy Event 2", random, random));
            }
        };
    }

    public Date getRandomDate(Date base) {
        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
        date.setTime(base);
        date.add(Calendar.DATE, ((int) (Math.random() * 30)) + 1);    //set random day of month

        return date.getTime();
    }

    public Date getInitialDate() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar.FEBRUARY, calendar.get(Calendar.DATE), 0, 0, 0);

        return calendar.getTime();
    }

    public ScheduleModel getEventModel() {
        return eventModel;
    }

    public ScheduleModel getLazyEventModel() {
        return lazyEventModel;
    }

    private Calendar today() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DATE), 0, 0, 0);

        return calendar;
    }

    private Date previousDay8Pm() {
        Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
        t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
        t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) - 1);
        t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 8);

        return t.getTime();
    }

    private Date previousDay11Pm() {
        Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
        t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
        t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) - 1);
        t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 11);

        return t.getTime();
    }

    private Date today1Pm() {
        Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
        t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
        t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 1);

        return t.getTime();
    }

    private Date theDayAfter3Pm() {
        Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
        t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) + 2);
        t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
        t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 3);

        return t.getTime();
    }

    private Date today6Pm() {
        Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
        t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
        t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 6);

        return t.getTime();
    }

    private Date nextDay9Am() {
        Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
        t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
        t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) + 1);
        t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 9);

        return t.getTime();
    }

    private Date nextDay11Am() {
        Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
        t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
        t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) + 1);
        t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 11);

        return t.getTime();
    }

    private Date fourDaysLater3pm() {
        Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
        t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
        t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) + 4);
        t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 3);

        return t.getTime();
    }

    public ScheduleEvent getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(ScheduleEvent event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    public void addEvent() {
        if (event.getId() == null) {
            eventModel.addEvent(event);
        } else {
            eventModel.updateEvent(event);
        }

        event = new DefaultScheduleEvent();
    }

    public void onEventSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
        event = (ScheduleEvent) selectEvent.getObject();
    }

    public void onDateSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
        event = new DefaultScheduleEvent("", (Date) selectEvent.getObject(), (Date) selectEvent.getObject());
    }

    public void onEventMove(ScheduleEntryMoveEvent event) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Event moved", "Day delta:" + event.getDayDelta() + ", Minute delta:" + event.getMinuteDelta());

        addMessage(message);
    }

    public void onEventResize(ScheduleEntryResizeEvent event) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Event resized", "Day delta:" + event.getDayDelta() + ", Minute delta:" + event.getMinuteDelta());

        addMessage(message);
    }

    private void addMessage(FacesMessage message) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }
}
```

La estructura de directorios que tengo en mi aplicación empresarial es la siguiente (Esta hecha con Maven):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que me muestra al ejecutar la aplicación es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver el contenido de los  si que me los muestra pero el calendario como tal no y no entiendo por qué ya que he copiado el código tal cuál está en Primefaces.

**EDITO:** He estado revisando el log y me sale lo siguiente, creo que esta relacionado con el error pero como he dicho antes, no entiendo a que se debe :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias a todos :)

Comment: el `@PostConstruct` me hace pensar en Java-EE y algunos de sus típicos problemas, que tal si pasas la inicialización de tu `eventModel` a un constructor?

Comment: Nada, sigue sin funcionar. Me sigue mostrando lo mismo y no lo entiendo. Tengo el mismo código que en la página de PrimeFaces...

Comment: Hola Josemanuu. ¿ya probaste descargando directamente el showcase de Primefaces? http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/showcase/6.2/showcase-6.2.war Los colegas turcos de PrimeFaces no suelen poner todo el código necesario, sus ejemplos regularmente son incompletos. Las fuentes completas de todo el show case están en: https://github.com/primefaces/showcase/releases/tag/6_2

Comment: Sii era eso. He cogido lo que me has mandado y ese código si que funciona!! Muchas graciaas!!! Respondeme a la pregunta en lugar de comentarla porque si no no puedo darte la recompensa que puse

Comment: Quizá porque estás definiendo el Bean  como **@ManagedBean** y **@Named**. Tengo entendido que  es uno u otro. Quita **@ManagedBean** si estas usando CDI, de lo  contrario quita   **@Named**

Comment: Creo que deberías quitar el **@Named**, por el import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

cuando has seguido las instrucciones y parece que no te muestra nada, prueba añadiendo estos namespaces , muchas veces lo que vienen por defecto están obsoletos, a mi me paso lo mismo y ahora va perfecto. espero que esto te sirva.